# How to bind port in Heroku With Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Heroku makes error like this

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 
seconds of launch
```

I think port isn't make trouble But many documents say timeout is port trouble

My code

```
const port = process.env.port || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(process.env.port);
    console.log(`SERVER is running at ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use environmental variables on Heroku you need to set them in the dashboard. Open https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/YOUR_APP_NAME/settings, then click the `REVEAL CONFIG VARS` button. After that, you should get a possibility to set up environmental variables. Also, if you use the `.env` file you need to remove it.

Comment: Don't try to set `PORT` on Heroku. That gets set automatically.